# Is there an option to prevent dropdown() from closing when using pickerInput() inside it with R shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dropdown, shinydashboard

So pretty much as the title says, I am trying to create a dropdown in R shiny with several pickerInputs inside of them. I know it is necessary to use dropdown and not dropdownBttn because of the bootstrap compatibility issue. When I open the dropdown, I can see all my filters without any issues. Even when I click on one of the pickerInputs, the widget functions without any issues. However, when I try to click on another picker input or just to close the picker dropdown, the entire dropdown menu closes. As a user this would be really irritating. I know I could just use checkbox options or even another widget given the example below is only using the cars dataset but I want to be able to expand it to datasets where there may be greater than 4 choices and a pickerInput might be the best widget for filtering. I have included my code below for a workable example of the issue.

```
# *LIBRARIES* ----


library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)


# *UI* ----


ui <- shinyUI(
  # Main Dashboard Page
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "green",
    # Dashboard Header Settings ----
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Dashboard Showcase",
      # Notifications Bar ----
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "notifications",
        icon = icon("warning")
      ),
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "messages",
        icon = icon("envelope")
      ),
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "tasks",
        icon = icon("clipboard")
      )
      ),
    # Dashboard Sidebar ----
    dashboardSidebar(
      # Tab Navigation Menu ----
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Main Dashboard",
                 tabName = "tab1",
                 icon = icon("dashboard")
        ),
        menuItem("Dynamic Graph",
                 tabName = "tab2",
                 icon = icon("chart-line")
        )
      )
    ),
    # Dashboard Body ----
    dashboardBody(
      # Dropdown Filter selection ----
        dropdown(
          size = "lg",
          icon = icon("filter"),
          label = "Filters",
            uiOutput("mainfilters")
          ),
      # Creating Dynamic Tabs ----
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "tab1",
          class = "active"
        ),
        tabItem(
          tabName = "tab2"
          )
      )
    )


  )
)

# *SERVER* ----

server <- function(input, output){

  # Data Initialization ----

  mydata <- mtcars

  # Filters ----
    output$mainfilters <- renderUI({
      list(
          # Place your input filters in list form here
        fluidRow(column(6,
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "gearfilter",
                          label = "Select Number of Gears", 
                          choices = as.character(sort(unique(mydata$gear), 
                                                      decreasing = FALSE
                                                      )
                                                 ),
                          selected = as.character(unique(mydata$gear)),
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = list(
                            `actions-box` = TRUE
                            )
                        )
                 ),
                 column(6,
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "cylinderfilter",
                          label = "Select Number of Cylinders", 
                          choices = as.character(unique(mydata$cyl)),
                          selected = as.character(unique(mydata$cyl)),
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          # New updated options to use the live searching function of the widget.
                          options = pickerOptions(
                            actionsBox = TRUE,
                            selectedTextFormat = 'count>2', 
                            liveSearch = T)
                        )
                 )
        ),
        fluidRow(column(6,
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "vsfilter",
                          label = "Select Engine Type: ", 
                          choices = as.character(unique(mydata$vs)),
                          selected = as.character(unique(mydata$vs)),
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          # Widget Options
                          options = pickerOptions(
                            actionsBox = TRUE
                            )
                        )
                 ),
                 column(6,
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "trannyfilter",
                          label = "Select Transmission Type: ", 
                          choices = as.character(unique(mydata$am)),
                          selected = as.character(unique(mydata$am)),
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          # Widget options
                          options = pickerOptions(
                            actionsBox = TRUE
                            )
                        )
                 )
        )
      )
    })
  # Data Cleaning ----




  # Output Options ----

    #outputOptions(x = output, name = "mainfilters", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Did you try with `dropMenu`?

Comment: I was under the impression that dropMenu was exclusive to adding dropdowns to the dashboardHeader of the app. I was trying to include this dropdown in the dashboardBody section of the app

Comment: No, `dropMenu` is like `dropdown`, but it is better (according to the documentation).

Comment: Would you mind linking to the documentation for the dropMenu() function? I can't seem to find it among the shiny documentation.

Comment: Hey - any chance you ever figured out a solution for this? Running into same issue myself